# How do I manage to get the "Unsubscribe" link right next to the From address on Gmail?

Tags: google-schemas

I'm working on an email marketing project, and I'm trying to get that link shown on the emails sent from our servers.

I'm including the "List-Unsubscribe: , " header, besides other headers considered good practices by RFC, support.google, ...

Is it possible that we are doing something wrong on the headers construction?

**This is the link I'm talking about:**
[Unsubscribe link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SRs9j.png)

**Our headers:**

```
Received: by 10.37.51.2 with SMTP id z2csp2282796ybz; 
        Tue, 4 Oct 2016 09:32:50 -0700 (PDT) 
X-Received: by 10.159.48.147 with SMTP id j19mr2901380uab.45.1475598769950; 
        Tue, 04 Oct 2016 09:32:49 -0700 (PDT) 
Return-Path: <*****************@74344.returnpath.dattanet.com> 
Received: from mta107.185.esmkt.net (mta107.185.esmkt.net. [200.58.107.185]) 
        by mx.google.com with ESMTPS id 7si1993119vkg.227.2016.10.04.09.32.48 
        for <*****************@gmail.com> 
        (version=TLS1_2 cipher=ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256 bits=128/128); 
        Tue, 04 Oct 2016 09:32:49 -0700 (PDT) 
Received-SPF: pass (google.com: domain of bounces-*************=gmail.com@74344.returnpath.dattanet.com designates 200.58.107.185 as permitted sender) client-ip=200.58.107.185; 
Authentication-Results: mx.google.com; 
       dkim=pass header.i=@74344.senders.dattanet.com; 
       dkim=pass header.i=@gmail.esmkt.net; 
       spf=pass (google.com: domain of bounces-*************=gmail.com@74344.returnpath.dattanet.com designates 200.58.107.185 as permitted sender) smtp.mailfrom=bounces-***************=gmail.com@74344.returnpath.dattanet.com 
DKIM-Signature: v=1; a=rsa-sha256; c=relaxed/relaxed; s=esdkim; d=74344.senders.dattanet.com; h=From:Reply-To:List-ID:Sender:List-Unsubscribe:Subject:Content-Type:MIME-Version:To:Date:Message-ID; i=*************@74344.senders.dattanet.com; bh=8JDi/gUM6J+D33yKj8l/4tZW5kFud7LHPmwWlCcrfqU=; b=WPSqCxYnM9WW8keFP8N3R4QZ8LkGIkoT4tftaVM02NsTdY4krn51J4CFG0FvZ8bQhebdqwpg4mTw 
   SB14IkPGNVNHMgK2+u2q25f4Qa7psu/cc/lPL93ss++9H99JtdSakeimOhbHGy4O2zm9TVgQYiXu 
   eq/kTZs5pZUuW0/PPek= 
DKIM-Signature: v=1; a=rsa-sha256; c=relaxed/relaxed; s=dkim; d=gmail.esmkt.net; h=From:Reply-To:List-ID:Sender:List-Unsubscribe:Subject:Content-Type:MIME-Version:To:Date:Message-ID; bh=8JDi/gUM6J+D33yKj8l/4tZW5kFud7LHPmwWlCcrfqU=; b=hwo3JCkn4tLxNPZyDkpCc85ND9PMQxlIXKoQqmCERhBwmm70+/Ga53HLlpr82ENHeQ9wklyy26/G 
   jqAB9wla/JZhaBdL/QiibJZi4VuxuGHsOC3s4FuyU68VWnQLPKySvtMRVPkuD50M0Rz6uFCzWRYz 
   qkXj08TTGbSWEmu76sA= 
Precedence: bulk 
X-DM-SENDER: MAILTX 
From: *********@********.com 
Reply-To: **********@***********.com 
X-DM-Tracking-Domain: 1 
X-Mailer-CSID: 1BRsE7-1426929 
X-DM-Priority: 10 
X-Report-Abuse: Please report abuse for this campaign here: 
                        http://envialosimple.com/abuse/ 
List-ID: <74344:2> 
Sender: *******=******.com@74344.senders.dattanet.com 
Return-Path: bounces@74344.returnpath.dattanet.com 
List-Unsubscribe: <mailto:unsubscribe@74344.track.dattanet.com?body=#s-1key#223bdbd85ee9bc39069593195d9b8adadf8c694a340e311511028f29c29314b078d864a0660e40e88845201193021993d6b3fdec739d1c851b7960b2adb635a27c#e-1key#>, <http://74344.track.dattanet.com/track/click?u=unsubscribe&p=37343334343a3139373a3137383a303a303a30&m=2&s=043258db01b40ed12a95ef7f5f49a2b9> 
Subject: ************** 
Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary="=_e61683699dd8c4bbfbaf3f6d4aa2e716" 
MIME-Version: 1.0 
To: <**************@gmail.com> 
Date: Tue, 4 Oct 2016 13:32:47 -0300 
Message-ID: <0.0.5.A9F.1D21E5CF13826CA.129B3@mta107.185.esmkt.net>
```

**Thanks in advance!**

Answer (score 0):

Even i was trying something like that and found that it is google's which scrapes the data from the Email Body and puts and Unsubscribe link right next to the name.
List-Unsubscribe will and can only ensure that the UNSUBSCRIBE Link is present when you press the downward arrow next **to me** .

Answer (score 0):

The unsubscribe option is only shown for senders with a high reputation.

See [Gmail unsubscribe link does not appear](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28497332/1066234)

Answer (score -1):

As far as I know there is already an existing Gmail feature wherein you may opt to add "Unsubscribe" button.

From this [Gmail forum](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/gmail/mlKTqEuy9ZQ), suggested steps are as follows:

> - Log-in to your Google group.
> - Click on the Gear icon top right of the home page, from the drop-down select *"Group settings"*.
> - Click to expand *"Settings"* in the left panel, and click on *"Email Options"*.
> - In the right panel, under Email Footer you should be able to spot *"Display how to unsubscribe from this group by email"*.
> - Check the box to the left of it.
> - You will be prompted to save your changes on Exit.

Another option is to use this [add-on](https://sites.google.com/site/scriptsexamples/available-web-apps/mail-merge/documentation/email-delivery/how-to-insert-an-unsubscribe-link). As noted in the given link, with this add-on, it is your responsibility to add an unsubscribe link to your emails if you think it is needed.

> For now on, there is no built-in unsubscribe feature in the add-on. We recommend using Google Form to let people tell you they don't want to receive your emails anymore. People will fill the form, submit their email address and you will be able to remove those email addresses from your mailing list to stop sending them emails.

Steps on how to implement this can be found in this given [documentation](https://sites.google.com/site/scriptsexamples/available-web-apps/mail-merge/documentation/email-delivery/how-to-insert-an-unsubscribe-link) or you may also check this [article](https://support.yet-another-mail-merge.com/hc/en-us/articles/210757749) for the newer version.

Comment: Hi Teyam, thanks for your answer, but we are not working with a Google Group, this is an Email Marketing project, like MailChimp. I've added an image on the original post that shows the link I'm talking about.